# increase field value in printing report

Tags: report

sir/mam, I want to increase field value when printing access report

ex: field value using number 1 and 2 into 3 and 4 for the next page print, right now I'm using this code to print how many page base on field value on form

```
Private Sub cmdprint_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdprint_Click

Dim strWhere As String

If Me.Dirty Then    'Save any edits.
    Me.Dirty = False
End If

If Me.NewRecord Then 'Check there is a record to print
    MsgBox "Select a record to print"
Else
    strWhere = "[NomorUrut] = " & Me.[NomorUrut]
    DoCmd.OpenReport "SPK", acViewPreview, , strWhere
    'create the message box
    Dim prnt As Integer
    'PRNT = MsgBox("Print" & "[Forms]![ScheduleNC Query1]![prnt].Value" & " Labels?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Question")
    prnt = MsgBox("Print?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Question")

    If prnt = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , [Forms]![ScheduleNC Query1]![prnt].Value

        DoCmd.Close
    Else
    DoCmd.Close
    End If
End If

'DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 8, , acMenuVer70
'DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection, , , , [Forms]![ScheduleNC Query1]![PRNT].Value

Exit_cmdprint_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdprint_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdprint_Click

End Sub
```

somebody help me please..thank you for your attention and reply...
try using [page], but my first page is 2 column so number 1 and 2 in the first page